Manual partitioning issue with Ubuntu installation on Lenovo device next
I cannot click the final Next button. I have Windows installed on the other partition. Help me with the partitioning in the Ubuntu installer.


Select the device where Grub, boot loader installation will be installed

Are you creating a second ESP - efi system partition? Only one per drive for almost all systems.
